# How to construct an SMA feedline for a horn antenna

Tags: antenna, coax, waveguide

I'm constructing an sma coax to waveguide transition for a horn antenna. Here's a cross-sectional view of what the device will look like

[image]

I can 3d print the waveguide portion (I use a conductive paint on the inside) but I'm wondering about how to get the coax connector right. I was thinking about purchasing a panel mount sma with a long feedline like [this](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex/0732510410/WM5383-ND/2755899) and then cutting the insulation with an xacto knife and clipping the metal feed with some sort of metal cutters (e.g. [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00002N5KQ)). I'll cut the insulation so that it doesn't extend into the waveguide portion of the transition and the feedline to be half the height of the waveguide. Are there any issues with this plan?

Would it be better to get an sma mount with a shorter feed and solder a piece of wire to the end to get the right length? If this is the case, can I get away with 18AWG solid core copper wire?

Is it a problem that there will be a portion of the waveguide inner surface that isn't conductive (where the insulation of the coax connector ends)? Any other thoughts?

I know this device will be far from perfect. It's for personal, recreational use so that's ok. But I would like it to be as good as possible with the materials I have.

Comment: I would go for the latter option of using a regular SMA mount with a stiff wire soldered to the center conductor because you can always unsolder it and tune it to get good performance (hope you have an antenna analyzer).

Comment: As for the wire, 18awg cu might be too flexible. I've seen some people use a plastic sheath around the antenna so that it stays straight, and since you have a 3D printer that might work well. It might affect the impedance though, so I'd do some EM simulations if that's available, or it might need additional tuning.

Comment: I can simulate but unfortunately I don't have a VNA yet, that's my next project... Obviously difficult to be precise with this, but you're thinking more like 16 or 14awg?

Comment: I'm thinking a brass rod so it's less bendy.